# Why : A PMD rule without 'ref' attribute can't be imported. see 'null'?

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd

I'm trying to create a quality profile in Sonar 3.0.1 and to specify my pmd configuration file.
But when I submit it, I've got the following error :

```
A PMD rule without 'ref' attribute can't be imported. see 'null'
```

Here the content of my extension file (sample taken at Sonar site)  :

```
<rules>
  <rule key="AvoidIfWithoutBrace">
    <name>Avoid if without using brace</name>
    <configKey>rulesets/extensions.xml/AvoidIfWithoutBrace</configKey>
    <category name="Usability" />
    <description>éviter les if sans crochet.</description>
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Despite my search, I didn't find the reason of this error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing concepts.

If you create a profile from the Web UI ([see the documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-CreatingProfile)), then you need to specify a PMD file, i.e. a file with the PMD format that looks like this:

```
<ruleset>
  <rule ref="rulesets/design.xml/SingularField">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  ...
</ruleset>
```

What you're currently giving to Sonar is a file with the Sonar format (which is the format that you can use to backup/restore full quality profiles).

Comment: But I don't understand the difference between in the GUI creating a profile and setting an pmd configuration file referencing rules, and putting in /extensions/rules/pmd directory a sonar extension file (like the one I described above) + a jar embedding rules.

Comment: finally it's ok, sorry for my last comment.